# Erro ao usar AdRequest

Tags: java, android

Poderiam me ajudar a achar o erro neste método OnCreate especificadamente na classe AdRequest?

---

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPageAdapter(getBaseContext()));

    mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
}
```

Algum dos componentes aparentemente está entrando em conflito com o adRequest pois testei o :

```
mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

em outra aplicação para testar se era este código , e ele funcionou , então o problema só pode ser no OnCreate

### Segue abaixo o erro do logcat

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                               Process: br.com.paivasdev.fazendocafe, PID: 5792
>                                                                               java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{br.com.paivasdev.fazendocafe/br.com.paivasdev.fazendocafe.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3319)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325)
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                                                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
>                                                                                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual
>   method 'void
>   com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView.loadAd(com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest)'
>   on a null object reference
>                                                                                   at
>   br.com.paivasdev.fazendocafe.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:50)
>                                                                                   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6904)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1136)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3266)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3415) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:229) 
>                                                                                   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1821) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>                                                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7325) 
>                                                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)

---

Comment: Você recebeu alguma mensagem de erro? Se sim, adicione a sua pergunta

Comment: Se você deixar só a 1 e 2 linha funciona?

Comment: `R.id.adView` existe no layout *activity_main*?

Comment: Sim existe estranho dar esse erro

Comment: O erro indica que `mAdView` é nulo, não encontro outra razão para isso acontecer que não seja ele não existir no layout *activity_main*

Comment: Tentou renomear o "adView" para outro nome qualquer no XML? Porque pode estar dando conflito com outros IDs.

Comment: E você inicializou o ADMOB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Após a [criação de uma conta no AdMob](https://www.google.com/admob/?subid=WW-EN-ET-firebase-docs&utm_source=internal&utm_medium=et&utm_campaign=firebase-docs&hl=pt-br), veja abaixo uma [forma resumida e funcional](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/quick-start?hl=pt-br) para criação de *banners* de notícias em sua aplicação e faça uma comparação com seu código.

**build.gradle**:

Verifique primeiro a [ultima versão disponível do Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android?hl=pt-br) para importar as libs no seu projeto.

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'
}
```

**main.xml**

É importante não esquecer de usar o `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` no XML. Veja:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
package ...

import ...
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

Por ultimo dê permissão para que sua aplicação acesse a internet. Caso não tenha permissão, os *banners* não aparecerão.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: AckLay , coloquei como resposta da postagem o erro do logcat

Comment: Paiva verifique seus imports se estão iguais aos meus.  `import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;`

Comment: Se eu for colocar no comentario , vai ultrapassar o numero de caracteres ...

Comment: @Paiva não é no comentário, é [EDITAR](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/191856/edit) a pergunta e colocar o erro nela.

Comment: Os imports estão iguais sim , editei  a postagem e coloquei o erro

Comment: Valeu cara! Eu estava errando na hora de importar as libs.