# Android Studio não importa AdRequest nem AdView

Tags: android

A parte que fica escrito android de ambos ficam vermelha e não importam

```
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
```

---

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import com.seamusdawkins.R;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;




public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        AdView mAdView = (AdView) view.findViewById(R.id.ad);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);

        return view;
    }


}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Já tentei importar de outra forma apertando <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd> no Adview porem não aparece a opção de importar

Comment: da uma olhada nesse link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39675100/error-cant-resolve-symbol-adrequest-and-adview parece com o seu problema

Comment: Gradle? compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'

Comment: Era as dependências mesmo kk obrigado

Comment: @Paiva conseguiu resolver o problema ou precisa de mais alguma informação. A resposta abaixo ajudou?! hehe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Acho que você está com um sério problema com o `AdView`. Para não estar aparecendo opção de importar, só tem um motivo: Não compilou a *lib* no `Gradle`. Veja como:

```
dependencies {
     compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:9.6.1'
}
```

Nesta opção opção acima, estará importando a versão `9.6.1`, no então é aconselhavel entrar no [*Release Notes* do Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android) e verificar qual versão mais atualizada.

Aqui nesta nessa pergunta sobre [Erro ao usar AdRequest](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/191873/35406) tem uma resposta mais completa de como você pode usar o [AdMob](https://www.google.com.br/admob/).